# Keep getting prompted to login Azure via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I've been running a relatively simple script to log into Azure (where I get an interactive window), and when I run a check to see if a name is available, I'm prompted to login again:

```
# Install the Azure Resource Manager modules from PowerShell Gallery
# Takes a while to install 28 modules
Install-Module AzureRM -Force -Verbose
Install-AzureRM

# Install the Azure Service Management module from PowerShell Gallery
Install-Module Azure -Force -Verbose

# Import AzureRM modules for the given version manifest in the AzureRM module
Import-AzureRM -Verbose

# Import Azure Service Management module
Import-Module Azure -Verbose

# Authenticate to your Azure account
Login-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionId 'xxxxxxxx'

# Adjust the 'yournamehere' part of these three strings to
# something unique for you. Leave the last two characters in each.
$URI       = 'https://someurlhere.com/azuredeploy.json'
$Location  = 'east us'
$rgname    = 'yournamehererg'
$saname    = 'yournameheresa'     # Lowercase required
$addnsName = 'yournameheread'     # Lowercase required

# Check that the public dns $addnsName is available
if (Test-AzureRmDnsAvailability -DomainNameLabel $addnsName -Location $Location)
{ 'Available' } else { 'Taken. addnsName must be globally unique.' }
```

Initially, the login works, shows up with my subscription, but when I execute the last command... I get:

```
Test-AzureRmDnsAvailability : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
```

I can't get anything to execute at all past this point. It's really frustrating. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this work in powershell if you were to run the command separately?  Can you confirm the version of AzureRM you are using?

Comment: Is there anything you're needing to do that isn't supported by the new Azure CLI 2.0? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli - I've been using this on OS X, in Powershell, and in a Docker container with some good success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, we should do some check:

1.Run `Get-Command Test-AzureRmDnsAvailability` to find this command:

```
PS C:\Users> Get-Command Test-AzureRmDnsAvailability

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Test-AzureRmDnsAvailability                        3.3.0      AzureRM.Network
```

2.Run `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` to check the Azure PowerShell version, my Azure powershell version is 3.3.0, I am able to run this script:

```
PS C:\Users> Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.3.0      Azure                               {Get-AzureAutomationCertificate, Get-AzureAutomationConnection, New-AzureAutomationConnection, Remove-AzureAutomationConnection...}
```

For test, we should run `Test-AzureRmDnsAvailability` separately.

For now, the latest release version is 3.8.0, more information about Azure PowerShell please refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Also you can download the Azure PowerShell installation file, and install it on your local PC. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v3.7.0-March2017/azure-powershell.3.7.0.msi